# Ruby on Rails: render form on a shared folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, render

I want to put the form on a shared folder for DRY the code and render this form for [:admin, :posts] and :posts.
So I create a folder and put the form on `app/views/shared/_form.html.slim`

```
- if params[:admin][:posts]
  post = [:admin, @post]
- if params[:posts]
  post = @post

= simple_form_for(post, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
   = f.association :categories, label: "Select the Categories:", as: :check_boxes , collection: @categories.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, include_hidden: false
   = f.input :title
   = f.input :subtitle
   - if @post.attachment.present?
     .attachment
       p
         = image_tag(@post.attachment.thumb.url, alt: 'Image', class: "img-responsive img-thumbnail")
         = f.check_box :remove_attachment
         | Remove image
         br
          .text-center
            small
              sample
                = "File_size #{number_to_human_size(@post.attachment.size)}"
   = f.input :attachment, as: :file, label: "File"
   = f.input :attachment_cache, as: :hidden
   = f.input :remote_attachment_url, label: "Enter URL to an image"
   = f.input :content, size: "150x150"

   = f.button :submit, class: 'btn-primary'
```

and then on

`app/views/admin/post/new.html.slim` and `app/views/posts/edit.html.slim`

I added the render:

```
== render 'shared/form', post: @post
```

So I tried to run and I have this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
    1: - if params[:admin][:posts]
    2:   post = [:admin, @post]
    3: - if params[:posts]
    4:   post = @post
```

This is just an idea that I have. it's ok for do this in this case or forget to do this?

routes:

```
rake routes | grep post
Running via Spring preloader in process 2187
             admin_posts POST   /admin/posts(.:format)                   admin/posts#create
          new_admin_post GET    /admin/posts/new(.:format)               admin/posts#new
              admin_post DELETE /admin/posts/:id(.:format)               admin/posts#destroy
nullify_posts_admin_user PATCH  /admin/users/:id/nullify_posts(.:format) admin/users#nullify_posts
                    root GET    /                                        posts#index
         published_posts GET    /posts/published(.:format)               posts#published
             draft_posts GET    /posts/draft(.:format)                   posts#draft
            recent_posts GET    /posts/recent(.:format)                  posts#recent
            publish_post PATCH  /posts/:id/publish(.:format)             posts#publish
          unpublish_post PATCH  /posts/:id/unpublish(.:format)           posts#unpublish
                   posts GET    /posts(.:format)                         posts#index
               edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                posts#edit
                    post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                     posts#show
                         PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                     posts#update
                         PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                     posts#update
```

Comment: `params[:admin]` returns `nil` and thus `[:posts]` raises an error. you could change this to `- if params[:admin] && params[:admin][:posts]` but since you are passing a local `post` to the partial setting it again does not make much sense. I guess you could change this `== render 'shared/form', post: @post` to `== render 'shared/form', post: params[:admin] && params[:admin][:posts] ? [:admin,@post] : @post` although I still do not enjoy this style but without a better understanding of implementation I am not sure I can propose a better solution

Comment: it's because for now on this application the admin is the only who can create the post. Then the others who have a role can edit.

Comment: I tried this and  shows the form but for create on the new action don't work's and the action edit work's well. the error was: `No route matches [POST] "/posts"`. Thank's for your help @engineersmnky!

Comment: Can we see your route.rb part about post and admin ?

Comment: I don't know why occur this, before I trying this DRY with shared. It work's normally. thank's for reply @Poilon. I edit the question and put the routes there.

Comment: seems like you don't have a POST on /posts route on your routes.rb.

Comment: it's because the post for posts is in the admin. But I do the way I want with the help of theTaryn East. Anyway thank you @Poilon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that what you're trying to do is figure out whether you're in the admin section or the standard post section and change the url of the form that way.

This is a bit of a non-standard way of doing it.
Generally speaking, what I've seen is that only the body of the form is in the shared form section, but the action is saved in the outside partial so eg:

app/views/admin/post/new.html.slim:

```
= simple_form_for(post, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
  == render 'shared/post_form', f: f, post: post
```

app/views/shared/_post_form.html.slim:

```
   = f.association :categories, label: "Select the Categories:", as: :check_boxes , collection: @categories.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, include_hidden: false
   = f.input :title
   = f.input :subtitle
   - if post.attachment.present?
     .attachment
       p
         = image_tag(post.attachment.thumb.url, alt: 'Image', class: "img-responsive img-thumbnail")
         = f.check_box :remove_attachment
         | Remove image
         br
          .text-center
            small
              sample
                = "File_size #{number_to_human_size(post.attachment.size)}"
   = f.input :attachment, as: :file, label: "File"
   = f.input :attachment_cache, as: :hidden
   = f.input :remote_attachment_url, label: "Enter URL to an image"
   = f.input :content, size: "150x150"

   = f.button :submit, class: 'btn-primary'
```

Note: if you pass `post` as a local variable into a form, you should use it with `post` not `@post` (because `@post` completely ignores the local variable you passed in and goes back to whatever came from the controller, in which case why bother passing in the local variable?)
You should also probably never call another variable `post` inside the template... as it overrides the old `post` variable and is then gone. Name it something different eg in this case, if you REALLY wanted to use the template the way you have been, you could call it `post_url_params`

Comment: Thank you @Taryn East. Your idea work's. I forget to use these blocks.

Answer (score 0):

So following the idea of the @Taryn East, I put this and work's:

app/views/admin/posts/new.html.slim

```
= title("New Post")
.header
  h1 New Post

== render 'form', post: @post
```

app/views/admin/posts/edit.html.slim

```
= title("Edit Post", @post.title)

.header
  h1 Edit Post

== render "form", post: @post
```

app/views/admin/posts/_form.html.slim

```
= simple_form_for([:admin, post], :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
  == render "shared/post_form", f: f, post: post
```

app/views/posts/_form.html.slim

```
= simple_form_for(post, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
  == render "shared/post_form", f: f, post: post
```

app/shared/_post_form.html.slim

```
= f.association :categories, label: "Select the Categories:", as: :check_boxes , collection: @categories.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, include_hidden: false
= f.input :title
= f.input :subtitle
- if post.attachment.present?
  .attachment
    p
      = image_tag(post.attachment.thumb.url, alt: 'Image', class: "img-responsive img-thumbnail")
      = f.check_box :remove_attachment
      | Remove image
      br
       .text-center
         small
           sample
             = "File_size #{number_to_human_size(post.attachment.size)}"
= f.input :attachment, as: :file, label: "File"
= f.input :attachment_cache, as: :hidden
= f.input :remote_attachment_url, label: "Enter URL to an image"
= f.input :content, input_html: { rows: '15' }

= f.button :submit, class: 'btn-primary'
```